# How to display selected data in a few drop down list

Tags: sql, field

I've a select statement which selects a few row of data from table. It is because the insertion have a few data, and the differences is only a serialno which is auto increment.
So how do i display this selected data in different field. Example
  " scrubnurse1 snrole1 , scrubnurse2, snrole2"...

This the data in the table

```
Serialno    SurgID                  RN_No      Surg_Date    ScrubNurse SNRole
13  rand52fad26a29c1c8.65850718     RN001-13   2014-02-10   016084     S
14  rand52fad26a29c1c8.65850718     RN001-13   2014-02-10   015294     S
15  rand52fad80207b6a1.33040579     RN001-13   2014-02-10   015356     S
16  rand52fad80207b6a1.33040579     RN001-13   2014-02-10   015405     C
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: Do you mean change rows to columns?

Comment: Which database do you need query for? Is there a upper limit to number of rows per SurgID? How is the expected output look like?

Comment: no upper limit of rows per Surg Id

Comment: i want to display each row that related to SurgID and RN No, and display in 4 column. ie.. column scrubnurse1, snrole1, scrubnurse2, snrole...and etc